# Using terraform to launch a .war file onto app service in azure

Tags: azure, terraform

I am trying to deploy a war file onto azure using terraform. I got a couple of errors

> Error: creating Blob "ram.war" (Container "terraformappsvc" / Account "accountstoragsec2"): PutBlockBlobFromFile: Error putting bytes: blobs.Client#PutBlockBlob: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="ContainerNotFound" Message="The specified container does not exist.\nRequestId:5eb9168a-601e-0068-34d9-cacaad000000\nTime:2023-08-09T15:49:05.0068585Z"
> │
> │   with azurerm_storage_blob.blobexample,
> │   on main2.tf line 74, in resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample":
> │   74: resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {

second error

> Error: creating/updating App Service VNet association between "terraformappsvc" (Resource Group "resoursegrpthree") and Virtual Network "virnetxample": web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdateSwiftVirtualNetworkConnectionWithCheck: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=404 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=404 Code="NotFound" Message="Cannot find VirtualNetwork with name virnetxample." Details=[{"Message":"Cannot find VirtualNetwork with name virnetxample."},{"Code":"NotFound"},{"ErrorEntity":{"Code":"NotFound","ExtendedCode":"51004","Message":"Cannot find VirtualNetwork with name virnetxample.","MessageTemplate":"Cannot find {0} with name {1}.","Parameters":["VirtualNetwork","virnetxample"]}}]
> │
> │   with azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection.example,
> │   on main2.tf line 82, in resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example":
> │   82: resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {

The code I used to create is

```
    provider "azurerm" {
     features {}
   }

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg2" {
  name     = "resoursegrpthree"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtunet1" {
  name                = "virnetxample"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet1" {
  name                 = "sunetxample"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtunet1.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}


resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "azurewebapp2" {
  name                = "example-appservice-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice2" {
  name                = "terraformappsvc"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.azurewebapp2.id

  site_config {
    java_version = "1.8"
    java_container = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version = "8.5"
    app_command_line = ""
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM" = "false"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "ExampleDB"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=myserver;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=mydb;"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storagesecond2" {
  name                     = "accountstoragsec2"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storageofwebapp" {
  name                  = "webappcontainer"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {
  name                   = "ram.war"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "C:/Downloads/sample.war"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.id
  subnet_id      = "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000/resourceGroups/rg2/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virnetxample/subnets/sunetxample"
}

output "app_service_id" {
  value = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.id
}
```

Please help me with the or the code which is used to deploy sample .war using terraform.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to launch a .war file onto the app service in the Azure portal using Terraform and I was successfully able to provision it.

I tried the same code shared I ended up having a similar error so I ended by trouble shooting the error causing the blocker and making changes according to the requirement.

The first error mentioned in the query was saying that the container "terraformappsvc" does not exist in the storage account "`accountstoragsec2`". This could be because the container was never created, or it was deleted.

The second error mentioned in the query was saying that the virtual network `"virnetxample"` could not be found. This could be because the virtual network was never created, or it was deleted.

So along with these two, I make changes according to the requirement by adding a delegation to **"Microsoft.Web/serverFarms,"** which is necessary for the App Service VNet integration to work and also change the container name configured to **"azurerm_storage_blob"** with `azurerm_storage_container.storageofwebapp.name`.

My Terraform file configuration goes as follows

**main.tf**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg2" {
    name = "v-bolliv-Mindtree"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtunet1" {
  name                = "virnetxample"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet1" {
  name                 = "sunetxample"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtunet1.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

    delegation {
    name = "AppService"
    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_service_plan" "azurewebapp2" {
  name                = "examplevk-appservice-plan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
  
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice2" {
  name                = "terraformappsvcvk"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_service_plan.azurewebapp2.id

  site_config {
    java_version = "1.8"
    java_container = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version = "8.5"
    app_command_line = ""
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM" = "false"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "ExampleDB"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=myserver;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=mydb;"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storagesecond2" {
  name                     = "accountstoragsec2vk"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storageofwebapp" {
  name                  = "webappcontainer"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {
  name                   = "sample.war"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.storageofwebapp.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "C:/Users/v-bolliv/Downloads/sample.war"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet1.id
}

output "app_service_id" {
  value = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.id
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @VinayakumarBolli Thank you. Everything got created but when I open the app service and click on default domain it is not opening the sample .war application which should work. Any leads on this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @Lekha Please check Application Deployment, App Service Settings and Configuration & Storage and Access to .war File once

Comment: Can you please complete the code and show me how did it work for you. I tried the modified code but the app service is not showing. Could you please demonstrate with code and pictures?

Comment: For reference check with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76948888/terraform-code-how-to-deploy-a-war-file-from-local-computer-downloads-onto-azure