# Terraform Code How to deploy a war file from local computer downloads onto Azure app service

Tags: azure, terraform

I have my .war file in downloads. I want to deploy it onto the app service. So for that I created a container and deployed the .war file onto the container. I am not sure how the connection between app service and storage works. I tried the following code:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg2" {
  name     = "resoursegrpthree"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtunet1" {
  name                = "virnetxample"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet1" {
  name                 = "sunetxample"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtunet1.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "delegationapp2"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "azurewebapp2" {
  name                = "example-appservice-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "B1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice2" {
  name                = "terraformappsvc"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.azurewebapp2.id

  site_config {
    java_version = "1.8"
    java_container = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version = "9.0"
    remote_debugging_enabled = true
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM" = "true"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "ExampleDB"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=myserver;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=mydb;"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storagesecond2" {
  name                     = "accountstoragsec2"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storageofwebapp" {
  name                  = "webappcontainer"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  container_access_type = "private"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {
  name                   = "ram.war"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.storageofwebapp.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "C:/Users/s***/Downloads/My_App.war"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "netswixam" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet1.id
}
```

The above code successfully created container and my file from downloads is in the container.
But when I click on the app service domain URL, I cannot open the application. Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> I try to write the Terraform Code on How to deploy a war file from local computer downloads onto the Azure app service

Merely relying on Terraform isn't enough to facilitate the deployment of a `.war` file from Azure Blob Storage to an Azure Web App. While Terraform is adept at establishing and setting up your infrastructure, an additional deployment script is recommended for orchestrating the deployment process effectively.

However need to look after these steps before

1. Ensure your  `.war`  file is in Azure Blob Storage.
2. Generate a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token for the blob for secure download.
3. Use a script that deploys the  `.war`  file via the Kudu REST API.
4. Use a deployment pipeline in azure devops or any other CI/CD Tool to run the script and deploy.

Here's a basic example using curl:

**#!/bin/bash**

```
# Variables
WEBAPP_NAME="your_webapp_name"
RESOURCE_GROUP="your_resource_group"
WAR_FILE_URL="https://your_storage_account.blob.core.windows.net/your_container/your_file.war?${SAS_TOKEN}"

# Get publishing profile for the Web App
PUBLISH_PROFILE=$(az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name $WEBAPP_NAME --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP --query "[?publishMethod=='MSDeploy'].{user:userName,pass:userPWD}" -o tsv)

# Extract username and password
USERNAME=$(echo $PUBLISH_PROFILE | awk '{print $1}')
PASSWORD=$(echo $PUBLISH_PROFILE | awk '{print $2}')

# Use Kudu REST API to deploy the war file
curl -X POST -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -d "{\"packageUri\":\"$WAR_FILE_URL\"}" \
     "https://$WEBAPP_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/wardeploy"
```

**My terraform Configuration:**

```
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg2"{
    name = "bolliv"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "virtunet1" {
  name                = "virnetxample"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "snet1" {
  name                 = "sunetxample"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.virtunet1.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
  delegation {
    name = "delegationapp2"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "azurewebapp2" {
  name                = "example-appservice-plan"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  kind                = "Linux"
  reserved            = true
  sku {
    tier = "Standard"
    size = "B1"
  }
}





resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storagesecond2" {
  name                     = "accountstoragsecvk"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  location                 = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account_sas" "test" {
    connection_string = "${azurerm_storage_account.testsa.primary_connection_string}"
    https_only        = true
    resource_types {
        service   = true
        container = false
        object    = false
    }
    services {
        blob  = true
        queue = false
        table = false
        file  = false
    }
    start   = "2018-03-21"
    expiry  = "2020-03-21"
    permissions {
        read    = true
        write   = true
        delete  = false
        list    = false
        add     = true
        create  = true
        update  = false
        process = false
    }
}

output "sas_url_query_string" {
  value = data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.test.sas"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "storageofwebapp" {
  name                  = "webappcontainer"
  storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  //container_access_type = "public"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_blob" "blobexample" {
  name                   = "demovk.war"
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.storagesecond2.name
  storage_container_name = azurerm_storage_container.storageofwebapp.name
  type                   = "Block"
  source                 = "C:/Users/v-bolliv/Downloads/demovk.war"
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "netswixam" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.appservice2.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.snet1.id
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "appservice2" {
  name                = "terraformappsvk"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg2.name
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.azurewebapp2.id

  site_config {
    java_version = "1.8"
    java_container = "TOMCAT"
    java_container_version = "9.0"
    remote_debugging_enabled = true
  }

  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM" = "true"
  }

  connection_string {
    name  = "ExampleDB"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=myserver;User Id=myuser;Password=mypassword;Initial Catalog=mydb;"
  }

    provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "./deploy_war.sh"
    environment = {
      SAS_TOKEN = data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.example.sas
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Once you're done with configuration as per the requirement a connection was established between the Azure & blob and this lets you access the Java application you're looking for.